# Remote sensing for Nepal Earthquake

Tags: remote-sensing, emergency-services, sentinel-1, natural-disaster, nepal

To any experts who can provide remote sensing data that can help assess impact and damage of nepal earthquake we really need your help to ensure aid is well targeted.

Existing data so far is [here](https://data.hdx.rwlabs.org/group/nepal-earthquake)

If you can supplement with for example sentinel-1 SAR data, building damage, population densities etc. This could be very useful

Please add relevant dataset in well labelled formats that are accessible and understandable to non gis experts to the [humanitarian data exchange](https://data.hdx.rwlabs.org/group/nepal-earthquake) and or other networks you known.

Please explain any uncertainties and document clearly.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the work being done by the [Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team (HOT) in response to the earthquake](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/2015_Nepal_earthquake)?

Comment: NASA Landsat on AWS http://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/ tiffs http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/index.html

Comment: Great resources. Many thanks but dont have time to do detailed analysis or GIS work. Internet also not so strong. Would value people who can use Sentinel-1 to estimate damage and people who can extrapolate figures for beneficiaries and associated age/sex disaggregations from something like www.worldpop.org

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - while it's an important mission - a call for action does not fit our Q&A format.

Comment: Please be aware of the GIS Meta discussion at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/what-gis-stack-exchange-avenues-are-available-to-enlist-community-support-for-em where @whuber makes some good suggestions about Community Promotion Ads.

Comment: @underdark fair enough to close. i realise its off topic. just pushing all the buttons here :)

Comment: Keep an eye here too http://www.unitar.org/unosat/maps

Comment: I've added a Meta answer at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3947 to try and assist procedurally during this and future emergencies of similar magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Keep an eye on [Tomnod](http://www.tomnod.com/), a crowd-sourced imagery review organization utilizing DigitalGlobe satellite imagery. They may be able assist.

Comment: I really fail to see why this answer is generating so many downvotes. The question asks for RS sources and analysis and the answer mentions a site/service that is both, and has been used extensively in the past *just for this purpose*.